# How to copy parts of string in another strings?

Tags: c#, string

I want to send multi attach in email, but have problem with those. When I put all files what want to send in one string always get error, but when put one file in one attach inside of loop thing work.

**Now I have problem with copying one part of string in to another strings, don't know how to do that, do you have some solution?**

Example:

txtattach.Text = "d:\\folder\\file1,d:\\folder\\file2,d:\\folder\\file3";

want to get 3 strings with context of location without "," that I can easy put it in loop.

Answer (score 7):

use the split function:

```
string[] paths = txtattach.Text.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using the [Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) so you easily can iterate over the items in a loop:

```
foreach(var filename in txtAttach.Text.Split(','))
{
 // Do something with filename
}
```